# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daterangepicker

Ive been working on adding daterangepicker (https://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage) to a rails app, and successfully got it working. However today, out of nowhere, Ive started getting the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function` error in my console, and the page breaks. I havent changed my application.js, gemfile, nor stylesheets since it was working, hoping to get some assistance here. From doing some research it seems that the function is being loaded before jquery is, but I am mystified as to why this is happening.

Gem file:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'

gem 'momentjs-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap
//= require daterangepicker
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss

```
*= require jquery-ui
*= require daterangepicker
```

daterangepicker.js

```
$(function() {
  $('.daterange').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    locale: { format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'}
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( daterangepicker.js )`

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<%= javascript_include_tag "daterangepicker.js" %>
    <%= form_with scope: :export, url: history_export_path, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :created_at_range, :class => 'form-control daterange', value: @created_at_range %>
        <%= f.submit "Filter Histories"%>
        <% @export.date_scope(@start_date, @end_date).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).each do |history| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= history.success %></td>
                <td><%= history.message.to_s %></td>
                <td><%= history.created_at %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First think your daterangepicker js file has confusion with the daterangepicker plugin file. rename it or add a script tag at the end of your view file.

add javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag to application.html.erb

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

delete script tags, link tag and javascript_include_tag 'daterangepicker' your view, they are not necessary if you add dependency in your application.js and application.css[image: It work for me]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ive made those changes, and the error has disappeared from the console, but the page is still broken. Specifically, it seems to not be loading bootstrap at all, but just in this view. other parts of the application load bootstrap just fine.

Comment: look at [this](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap/4.0.0)